# How to properly store coordinates after using Graphics2D#drawString?

Tags: java, awt, textures, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'm trying to generate a dynamic image with the alphabet printed onto it. I'm making use of `java.awt.Graphics2D` to accomplish this. I create my image like so:

```java
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
final var image = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
var graphics = image.createGraphics();
{
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 48));
    var metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();

    for (int i = 0, x = image.getMinX(), y = metrics.getAscent() + image.getMinY(); i < alphabet.length(); ++i) {
        var alpha = alphabet.charAt(i);
        {
            var width = metrics.charWidth(alpha);
            var height = metrics.getHeight();
            if (x + width > image.getWidth()) {
                y += height;
                x = 0;
            }

            graphics.drawString(String.valueOf(alpha), x, y);
            x += width;
        }
    }
}
graphics.dispose();
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "image.png"));
```

Doing this, I am able to create a 256x256 image that contains the entire sequence of the alphabet, like below:

[image: sequence of the alphabet generated with the above code]

I want to, like previously stated, be able to target each individual character (in my case, it's specifically for OpenGL texture rendering), so having accurate x, y, width, and height coordinates are an absolute must. With that in mind, I'm trying to test if my coordinates are correct. In order to do that, I'm attempting to split each characters from the main image into their own sub images, then write those out using ImageIO. In order to store the data, I'm using a custom class called Glyph.

```java
public class Glyph {
    private final int x, y, width, height;

    public Glyph(final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // getters
}
```

To store information about each character, I decided to use a `java.util.Map<Character, Glyph>` to make my life a bit easier.

```java
var map = new HashMap<Character, Glyph>();
// previous code, up-to the Graphics2D#drawString part
map.put(alpha, new Glyph(x, y, width, height);
```

Once this list is populated, I try to grab a `BufferedImage#getSubimage`, then use `ImageIO#write` to visually see if it works. This is where the problem lies.

```java
map.forEach((c, g) -> {
    var sub = image.getSubimage(g.getX(), g.getY(), g.getWidth(), g.getHeight());
    ImageIO.write(sub, new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")), c + ".png");
});
```

The issue seems to reside either here, or how I'm getting my coordinates, because the images are wildly off. The subimages don't even contain anywhere close to the characters I'm expecting, which is confusing. I'm not sure if it's due to the fact that somehow, my coordinates are incorrect, or maybe getSubimage works a bit differently then I'd expect.

On my PC, here's a snippet of what all this code renders:

[image: messed up alphabet characters]

This obviously isn't ideal, and I don't understand what's happening at all. What might be going on?

Edit: For anyone confused about the usage of `var`, I am using Java 13.

Comment: The answer to the question would depend on if you're intending to use fixed or variable width fonts.  If you're using a fixed width font, then it's a simple matter of know how many columns/rows the text is laid out in.  If not, then it becomes complicated, as you need to store the x/y and width/height of each letter, I might consider using JSON or XML, depending on what libraries you have avaliable

Comment: I'm intending to support variable width fonts, which is why I opted to make use of `FontMetrics` alongside the `Map<Character, Glyph` for each character. Does `FontMetrics` not handle width problems, or am I missing your point?

Comment: I would say this is a do-and-test thing -  Look at here to educate yourself https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#charWidth(char)